# Ignore .DS_Store files on webdav server

Tags: apache, webdav

I have a webdav server running on Apache 2.4 on a FreeBSD box.

When Mac users connect to the server, they create a lot of files and directories starting with a dot. This is transparent to mac users, but pollute the server for Windows users...

I tried the following settings in the Apache config file without success:

```
IndexIgnore .*

<Files .*>
    Require all denied
</Files>

<FilesMatch "^\..+$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Please let me know, if you are able to hide these files (and directories) to Windows users.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (client-side)solution may be found here:
https://support.studionetworksolutions.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000949866-Prevent-creation-of-DS-Store-files-on-network-shares

To prevent the Mac workstation from creating .DS_Store files on network shares, as well as instruct it to ignore existing .DS_Stores, open Terminal and enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34680771)

Comment: OK, I updated it.